# Dart Null Safety: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have got the following Text( ... ) widget in my Flutter application

```
Text(
                                    data['location'],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 40, 
                                        letterSpacing: 2, 
                                        color: Colors.white
                                    )
```

However, it keeps showing me an error that the data['location'] cannot be accessed, as it can be null. I guess it has to do something with Dart's null safety checks

The flow of my code is something like this:

1. The data object that I am accessing in the Text( ... ) widget is declared above like this:

   ```
    Object? data;
   ```
2. Afterwards, when I pass data to this screen from another screen, I use the data object declared above and do the following assignment:

   ```
        data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
   ```
3. And, finally, in the end, I access this data object in my Text( ... ) widget

What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: You need to set `ModalRoute.of(context)`  value in case of null first. ModalRoute.of(context) == null ? defaultData : ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments; Or if you are ok with `data` be null just go with `data = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;`

Comment: @SimonSot the problem persists. It still gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - `data` is of  type `Object` so you can't use `[]` with `Object` type because it does not overload `[]` operator

2 - let assume that argument is of type `List` you must cast it first to `Map` then access the data from it like this

```dart
 (data as Map?)?["location"]
```

3 - `data` is nullable Type
all you need to do is to tell `dart` that I am sure that `data` is not null by bang operator

The finale code should like that:

```dart
Text(
  (data as Map?)?["location"]!, // <---
  style: TextStyle(
  fontSize: 40, 
  letterSpacing: 2, 
  color: Colors.white
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Hosam. Worked like a charm. I do have one question though: When I remove both the question marks in (data as Map?)?["location"]!, it still works fine. What could be the reason behind that?

Comment: it's weird to cast nullable type to non-nullable type without error, I think that some null safe features still not complete yet.
look here [cast_nullable_to_non_nullable](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/cast_nullable_to_non_nullable.html)

Answer (score 0):

[arguments](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteSettings/arguments.html) property has a return type of `Object?` which is the most generic type.

To make use of the actual data, you'll first need to use Typecast `as` operator.

```dart
var data = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>?;
```

Since `data` could be null

1. you'll need to either set a default value like:

```dart
data ??= {'location': 'behind you'}; // Avoids null access.
```

2. or if you are absolutely sure that the value won't be null:

```dart
data!['location']; // Will result in runtime exception if data is null.
```